# Generating 3X3 rank 1 PSD matrices that have one or zero on the diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

I need to be able to describe all rank 1, 3X3 PSD matrices that have 1 or 0 on the diagonal. My line of thinking is that 3x3 rank 1,PSD matrix $A$ has only a single singular value $ \sigma_1 $ that is not zero and therefore $ A = \sigma_1 u_1 u_1^\top $ where $u_1$ is the corresponding orthonormal eigenvector. Is this the correct line of  thinking  ? How do I continue from here ?

Edit:  based on the comments below my thinking is that any 3 dimensional vector $x$ with entries that are either 0,1,-1 can be used to  generate the required matrix by computing $x x^\top $. Is this correct ? Does it cover all the cases ?

Comment: You have taken care of rank 1 and PSD. Now investigate the remaining issue: How can you make the diagonal of such a matrix contain only $1$ and $0$?

Comment: That's right. As $\sigma_1 \ge 0$, you can even incorporate $\sqrt{\sigma_1}$ into $u_1$, and plainly consider matrices of the form $u_1u_1^T$